# MySQL: Select all distinct records, selecting the record with the latest timestamp for duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I have the following  pretty big table (350+ million rows):

```
Create table test(
col1 int, -- there is an index on this column
col2 datetime,
...
...

)
```

Sometimes I want to be able to pull only records that match against col1 however since there are duplicates, I want only the ones with the latest timestamp.

For example:

```
select * from test where col1 in (123, 389, 192) AND only give me the record for each match against col1 that has the latest timestamp.
```

So in a table that contains:

```
123, 2015-08-23,....
123, 2015-09-23,....
```

it would return only the second record for value 123 which has a date of 2015-09-23.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a derived table to get the `max` date for each `col1` and join the results back to the main table.

```
select t.* 
from test t
join (select col1, max(col2) as maxdate from test group by col1) t1
on t1.col1 = t.col1 and t1.maxdate = t.col2
where t.col1 in (123, 389, 192)
```

Comment: I should have probably put this in the question but this table can get pretty big (350 million rows) so I would be worried about the performance of this join.